# In XAMPP MySQL database is not starting

Tags: mysql, database

Although if have written some commands in terminal like this:

sudo killall mysql

sudo chmod -Rf 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: @4EACH, Starting MariaDB
.2018-07-08 19:58:37 11024 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro-Ajdyn.local.err'.
2018-07-08 19:58:37 11024 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
 ERROR!